# Puedo desmontar un componente desde su propio useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una variable `isDesktop` y quiero que cuando esta cambie, si es verdadera, el componente se desmonte. Hay alguna funcion para invocar al propio componente y desmontarlo?

La idea seria poner dicha funcion dentro de

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(isDesktop){
    // desmontar componente
  }
}, [isDesktop])
```

Comment: Esto contesta tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985738/how-to-unmount-unrender-or-remove-a-component-from-itself-in-a-react-redux-typ

Comment: @AndresGardiol no, pero refuerza mi teoria de que no puedo hacer algo exactamente asi, deberia disparar una funcion que llegue al padre y este deberia ser el encargado de desmontarlo. Muchas gracias. Se como hacer eso, por lo que, si no tengo mas alternativa, es lo que voy a intentar. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @AndresGardiol en realidad si la contesta, me dice que no puedo 

Comment: Claro, por eso te la compartí